# Having trouble styling SVG with CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

Hi I'm new to using SVG's but i thought the whole idea of SVG's is that you can change the background-color etc. Anyway i'm using the open sources clrs.cc and it has both svg fills and strokes built in but none work on my search icon.

```
<img src="ic_search_48px.svg" class="fill-navy" alt="This should be a search icon">
```

Here is what the CSS classes look like:

```
.fill-navy {
 fill: #001F3F; }
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: It does show up by the way, but in black.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? Ideally you can change the `fill` color of the `path` elements within SVG.

Comment: So SVG is like its own code language? Btw the search icon i just from Googles Material design.

Comment: Okay so how would i be able to change the color because the icon is avalible in png aswell so which one is easier to use? Thanks to everyone for answering btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you cannot change the color of an SVG used as an actual image or background-image.

CSS can only affect **inline** SVG in the page HTML.

EG.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.icon {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
.large {
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
}
.red {
  fill: red;
}
.green {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="hidden">
  <defs>
    <g id="search" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
      <path d="M31 28h-1.59l-.55-.55C30.82 25.18 32 22.23 32 19c0-7.18-5.82-13-13-13S6 11.82 6 19s5.82 13 13 13c3.23 0 6.18-1.18 8.45-3.13l.55.55V31l10 9.98L40.98 38 31 28zm-12 0c-4.97 0-9-4.03-9-9s4.03-9 9-9 9 4.03 9 9-4.03 9-9 9z" />
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 48 48">>
  <use xlink:href="#search" class="red" />
</svg>

<svg class="icon large" viewBox="0 0 48 48">>
  <use xlink:href="#search" class="green" />
</svg>
```

1. Extra Reading - [**Article @ CSS-Tricks.com**](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/)
2. Also - [**SVG Icons @ CSS-Tricks.com**](http://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/)